# Knockout.js dynamic composable table

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm trying to make a "dynamic table" with knockout js and I'm having a bit of difficulty. I want to have a "Common Row Template" with a nested template for the variable columns. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="CommonRow">
<td><input type="text" data-bind="value: Nome" /></td>
<td data-bind="template: { name: $item.LabelOne + 'Row' }"></td>
<td><button class="fancybox edit" data-bind="click: Edit">Modifica</button></td>
<td><button class="remove" data-bind="click: Remove">Rimuovi</button></td>
</script>
```

So the second `<td>` will render a template, which will look like this:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="ScalaRow">
<td><input type="text" data-bind="value: PianiFuoriTerra" /></td>
<td><input type="text" data-bind="value: Foo" /></td>
</script>
```

This "works" but it has a big problem: the desired `<td>` are nested in the outer `<td>` with the template binding, causing improper alignment with the header (which also is structured the same way).

I tried using the {{tmpl}} syntax to avoid the wrapping `<td>` and this gets me the right html, but all the databinding and observable don't work anymore in the dynamic part.

Is there a way to render a block of `<td>` preserving the knockout observable functionality and avoiding any wrapping tag? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to look at using [KO 1.3 beta](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/).  Here is a sample of doing something like what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/wmDfv/

```
<table data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <!-- ko template: type -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
</table>

<script id="typeA" type="text/html">
    <td>typeA template</td>
</script>

<script id="typeB" type="text/html">
    <td>typeB template</td>
</script>
```

Comment: I'm about to engrave your soul with the title of "Life Saver" but first lemme experiment a little :)

Comment: I'm trying to make it work, but 1.3 says that "my version of jquery.tmpl is old" and asks me to upgrade to "1.0.0pre or later" but I can only see on jquery.tmpl site that it never made it past beta and it's now dead. What am I supposed to use with knockout 1.3?

Comment: The latest version here will work: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl or grab it from: http://github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/jquery.tmpl.js.  Otherwise, you can consider just using the native template engine in 1.3.  If you look at my fiddle it does not reference jQuery tmpl at all.  You just can't use jQuery tmpl specific syntax ({{each}}, etc.), but you can now use the control-flow bindings for similar functionality (if, with, foreach).  Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Where can I find some reference about changes? Now I moved to native templates, and I'm getting an "$item is not defined" where I was using $item to access templateOptions properties.

Comment: Docs are not updated yet, but best spot is here: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/.  templateItem is not supported currently.  You might look at using $parent or $root instead, depending on your situation.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it differently, passing a composite data to the template, like data: { value: $data, myCustomValue: 'Foo' }